# VR/AR Toolkit issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge

I tried to create the Hello World example but when I play the scene I get the following error:

AsyncRequestCompleted The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Autodesk.Forge.ARKit.RequestQueueMgr:AsyncRequestCompleted(Object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs) (at Assets/Forge/CodeBase/RequestQueue.cs:322)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks()

The game scene then just displays as black. Any ideas? I'm using the latest toolkit (Nov 2018).

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the new version of the toolkit where certain web requests to the server would contain an unsupported HTTP header, ending with a 422 error code. On Wednesday, Jan 9, around 5:00PM CET, we deployed a fix to the production servers which addresses the issue. If you're still seeing the issue, please send us an email to forge [dot] help [at] autodesk [dot] com with details (urn, time of the request, etc.) and we'll get back to you.

Comment: Is this problem technically solved? Because Chris accepted this answer and I still get the error message. The URN, Token and Scene I tested are the parameters which I receive from the Sample Gallery (https://wallabyway.github.io/toolkitServerv2/)

Comment: Chris' issue has been related to an incorrect access token. Please note that if the access token you're pasting into Unity is incomplete or expired, you'll still get the 422 response.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just realized that I only copied a part of the Token because of the included dot. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) I’m thinking about adding a “Copy to Clipboard” button to all 3 fields. That would probably help :)